# UISearchBar Cancel Button

Tags: uisearchbar

Using a UISearchBar with showCancelButton=YES on iOS 5.  Would like the cancel button to stay enabled when the keyboard drops down.  Using the following code seems not to work:

```
for (id subView in self.searchControl.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)subView;
        [cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
        break;
    }         
}
```

The subView is actually a UINavigationButton which appears not to be subclassed off of UIButton.  What am I missing here??????? Also cannot find any info on the UINavigationButton class in the Apple docs.

Comment: As of now, none of the answers explain how you are supposed to find the cancel button. Byte's answer, for example just uses isKindOfClass: UIButton, which the OP has already said doesn't work. Since UINavigationButton is an undocumented class, then does that mean that any messages sent to the object will cause your app to be rejected?

Answer (score 24):

Set your searchbar delegate and than put this code.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*) theSearchBar
  {
     [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
     [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
  }
 - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
     [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
  }
  - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
     [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
  }
```

Swift 3.0

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
     searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
     searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5:**, **Swift 4:**

```
if let btnCancel = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    btnCancel.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to improve upon what Kurt Spindler said on his post. Though this might not be superior but it is more contained. I use dispatch to do the same thing.

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            int64_t delayInSeconds = .001;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                UIButton * cancelButton = (UIButton *)subview;
                [cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for everyone who needs help keep cancel enabled. Make sure that you hide it later either with the cancel or Search clicked.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you want to perform something asynchronously, just use dispatch_async. You don't need dispatch_after with an "almost instant delay value". E.g. in this case `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){...});` works perfectly fine.

Comment: I believe the 0.001 was necessary based on the answer by Kurt. If that is not the case, then your approach would be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve the same problem in my application. Try doing your above code after a fractional delay, e.g.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedEnable:) withObject:cancelButton afterDelay:0.001];

- (void)delayedEnable:(UIButton*)button {
    button.enabled = YES;
}
```

It's ugly, but that's what it took to work for me. Alternatively, if you actually use a UISearchDisplayController to display the results, it should also fix the cancel button behavior for you (I think - I've delved into this issue less).

Comment: This is working like a magic..@Kurt Can you tell me from where you got this? Amazing..upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I placed a custom cancel button over the search bar cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old, but I was able to solve it and I couldn't find anything else on SO that solved it for me, so here's what worked (in Swift 3):

Enable the cancel button when the keyboard hides. Add this to viewDidLoad():

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
```

in the keyboardNotification(notification:) method, react to the keyboardDidHide notification:

```
func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide {
        self.enableSearchCancelButton()
    }
}
```

The enableSearchCancelButton is taken from what others have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020452/enable-cancel-button-with-uisearchbar-in-ios8).

```
func enableSearchCancelButton() {
    //enable the cancel button
    for view1 in searchBar.subviews {
        for view2 in view1.subviews {
            if let button = view2 as? UIButton {
                button.isEnabled = true
                button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to remove the view controller as an observer:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```