# iOS - Customizing Cancel button of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, cancel-button

In my iOS5 iPhone application, i'm setting the tint color of search bar using following code:

```
searchBar.tintColor = UIColorMake(@"#EFEFEF");
```

RGB value of #efefef is (239,239,239) 
Its working fine. But when cancel button appears the text "Cancel" is not visible. Can I customize only the cancel button with transparent black and white text on that?

 is it possible to customize?

Comment: I have written an answer to this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206757/how-to-change-textcolor-of-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7. Just use the SHSearchBar which is not such a pain in the ass like the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could search for `UISearchBar` subViews and locate the cancel button, it is dangerous to do so, since the button could change
For example you could add this in your `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //show the cancel button in your search bar
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    //Iterate the searchbar sub views
    for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        //Find the button
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            //Change its properties
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)[sb.subviews lastObject];
            cancelButton.titleLabel.text = @"Changed";
        }
    }
}
```

As i said before this could change, its a hack to do so, you better stick with the original, or create your own search bar.

Comment: in ios 7 it's not finding any subviews

Comment: This is not advisable and as of iOS 5 the better way to handle this is with the appearance proxy as Marián Černý descibes in his answer.

Answer (score 42):

You can customize the Cancel button on iOS 5 by using the appearance proxy.
You need to change appearance of `UIBarButtonItem` when contained in `UISearchBar`.
For example to change the title font of the Cancel button you can use:

```
NSDictionary *attributes =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
     [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
     [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
     [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12], UITextAttributeFont,
     nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
    setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
    setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. It's not hacky, it's clear, and it works. The currently accepted answer could break at any time.

Comment: This is great for changing the text on the button, but how do you change the button itself? eg - change the button size

Comment: Unfortunately UISearchBar also contains a Clear button (grey circle with an x inside) so if you change Cancel button's background image using this method, Clear button is affected too...

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS5 you can edit the Navigationbar, Toolbar, Tabbar and some more with this code...

```
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                          UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                          [UIColor whiteColor], 
                                          UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```

I haven´t tested it with a searchbar, but it should work similar.

Comment: No it doesn't. If you look at the appearance documentation for the search bar, it does not provide a clear handler for changing the attributes of the search button.

Answer (score 0):

This method works in IOS7

```
for (UIView *view in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        for (id subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ( [subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] )
            {
                // customize cancel button
                UIButton* cancelBtn = (UIButton*)subview;
                [cancelBtn setEnabled:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150826/1767686