# Customising UISearchBar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` whose appearance I want to customise. The suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063619/1082181) worked before the update to iOS 7. But now I'm not sure how to do it. I mainly want to customise the Cancel button. Does anybody know how?

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956255/ios-change-the-title-of-cancel-button-in-uisearchbar/18956420

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS 7. The person who has answered that question has mentioned that he has only tried it on iOS 6.

Comment: Look at my answer to that question. Tried it and it works on iOS 7 :)

Comment: The recursive approach worked! Thank you. Maybe you should post it here so I can accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search for the button recursively. This should be a fail-safe way to do it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self convertButtonTitle:@"Cancel" toTitle:@"Annuller" inView:self.searchBar];
}

- (void)convertButtonTitle:(NSString *)from toTitle:(NSString *)to inView:(UIView *)view
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        if ([[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:from])
        {
            [button setTitle:to forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        [self convertButtonTitle:from toTitle:to inView:subview];
    }
}
```

I've tested this on iOS 7 only, but it works and should do so for iOS 6 too.

Comment: Thanks, also, I can't seem to be able to change the frame of the cancel button. Any idea why?

Comment: Nope, haven't had a chance to try that. Maybe try changing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Then it may require subclassing the UISearchBar.

Comment: Probably. I will try that too.