# change the name of the searchBar cancel button IOS 7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uisearchbar

I'm having trouble changing the text of the searchbar cancel button.

See my code:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [_srBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    UIButton *cancelButton = nil;
    for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Annuller" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}
```

Also I already tried other options

[iOS Change the title of cancel button in UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956255/ios-change-the-title-of-cancel-button-in-uisearchbar)
[iOS - Customizing Cancel button of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063527/ios-customizing-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar)

In this example my code does not call the method

[How to change the default text of Cancel Button which appears in the UISearchBar +iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536151/how-to-change-the-default-text-of-cancel-button-which-appears-in-the-uisearchbar)

my scenery

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface favorito : UIViewController<UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];

[barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setBackgroundImage:grayBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                      UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:20],
                                 UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor blackColor]
     } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitle:@"X"];
```