# How to change textColor of Cancel button of UISearchBar in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, textcolor

I need to change the color of Cancel button text of `UISearchBar` in iOS7.

Normally `UISearchBar` Cancel button `textColor` is blue and I want to change `textColor` to `redColor`.

[image]

How can i change it?

Comment: `Swift 4.2, 4.0+`, I have added an answer for multiple customizations including cancelButton for searchBar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345642

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found answers for my own questions.

Here is code , add in `AppDelegate` if you want to change all cancel button.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                                  [UIColor redColor],
                                                                                                  UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                                                                  [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                                                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                                                                  nil]
                                                                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift:

```
let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor etc. are deprecated in iOS7. Use NSForegroundColorAttributeName etc. instead.

Comment: I don't know if this worked before but as of 7.0.3 it DOES NOT work.

Comment: `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Comment: You can simply change the tint color!

Comment: UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.normal) Really helpful answer...!!

Answer (score 16):

If you only want to set the text color of the button, you only need one line:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this

```
[yourSearchBarName setTintColor:[UIColor whateverColorYouWant]];
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that it also sets the cursor color.

Answer (score 12):

A much simpler way -->

```
self.searchbar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Answer (score 12):

Updated for `Swift 5`:

```
let searchBarCancelButtonForegroundColor = UIColor.red
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: searchBarCancelButtonForegroundColor]

// Regular mode
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

// After click
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = searchBarCancelButtonForegroundColor
```

Worked for `SWIFT 4`

Use the `appearance` function of `UIAppearance` module -

**Method 1:-** Show cancel button on load with `searchBar` -

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

or -

**Method 2:**- 
Show cancel button color after `searchBar` clicked -

```
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 9):

You can change the subviews of the `UISearchBar` like this in `- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

```
UIView *view = [_searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)subView;
        [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
}
```

Comment: Digging through subviews is fragile way of doing this. Use the appropriate UIAppearance "when contained in" methods.

Answer (score 6):

You can format your searchbar cancel button as follows

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:@"Your Text Here"];
```

Hopes it works for you.

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 9. "Use +appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses: instead" from framework.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3:**

> Use this code to set Red color (text,
>   courser, button)

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .red
```

> if you want to change cancel button color to white add this code too

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

For swift 4.2

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to set the cursor and the button color independently is this: I set the cursor color to blue in the App Delegate (-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:):

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

And then use the search bar's tint color in each controller to set the buttons color. You can set the tint color even on the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Swift 4

```
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font            : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .medium),
                                          .foregroundColor : #colorLiteral(red: 0.1960784314, green: 0.1960784314, blue: 0.1960784314, alpha: 1)], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using Swift, I had to first add
[Eddie K's extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478867/845431)

Then I was able to call it like so (basically what Sabo did in the accepted answer):

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedWithin(UISearchBar.self).setTitleTextAttributes()
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextAttribute is depricated from IOS 7 use below for IOS 7 or later

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the UISearchBar would be the [SHSearchBar](https://github.com/Blackjacx/SHSearchBar). This swift framework is easily customizable without hacking, open source, has a lot of unit tests and is available via [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SHSearchBar). It needs at least iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
let uiButton = bar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton
uiButton?.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
uiButton?.setTitleColor(UIColor.white,for: .normal)
```