# Customize UISearchBar cancel button in IOS 7 building from Xcode 5.x

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I am using below code. It is working perfectly in IOS 6.x. building from Xcode 4.6.x . But that code is not working no more in IOS 7.x building from xcode 5.x.

My objective is to display a custom image in place of cancel button of UISearchBar when user start editing in UISearchBar.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    UIButton *cancelButton = nil;
    for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews){
        if([subView isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]){
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    [cancelButton setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customKeyboardIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Check this post. it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206757/how-to-change-textcolor-of-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7

Answer (score 6):

The cancel button in the `UISearchBar` is of type `UIBarButton`. They way I did it was the following (works on iOS 5,6,7) :

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:cancelButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you don't want the custom cancel button on all of you `UISearchBar`s, just create a custom `UISearchBar` class and replace the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class]` with your new custom made class.

For removing the text:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:@""];
```

As for the image, either you adjust your image resource, or you create an `UIImage` with some insets, (tinker with the insert until you get the expected result):

```
     UIImage *cancelButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:SEARCH_BAR_CANCEL_BUTTON];
cancelButtonImage = [cancelButtonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:CANCEL_BUTTON_IMAGE_INSETS];
```

Comment: It's setting background image but it's looking stretch and text cancel text is coming how to remove that text?

Comment: There are no selector of UIBarButtonItem as setTitle.

Comment: setTitle is a selector for appearance of the UIBarButton

Answer (score 0):

Check this code I use:

```
-(void) colorCancelButton
{
    UIButton *cancelButton = [self getCancelButton];
        [cancelButton setTintColor:[Util colorFromHex:@"#D6D1CF"]];
        [cancelButton setTitleColor:[Util colorFromHex:@"333333"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(UIButton*) getCancelButton
{
    UIButton *cancelButton = nil;
    for(UIView *subView in self.subviews){
        if([subView isKindOfClass:UIButton.class])
        {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    return cancelButton;
}
```