# How do you keep the cancel button in the search bar enabled when the keyboard is dismissed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchbar

[image] [image]

I'm trying to achieve the same effect as Apple's Contacts app (left screenshot). The cancel button in UISearchBar is enabled even when the keyboard is dismissed. My app behaves differently (right screenshot). The cancel button automatically becomes disabled when the keyboard is dismissed. The user is forced to tap the cancel button one time to enable it and then another time to actually trigger the dismissal. This is not good user experience. How would I always keep the cancel button enabled like Apple's Contacts app?

**Technical Details:**

I'm not using `UISearchDisplayController` due to some design requirements. This is just a `UISearchBar` with my own custom search controller. The cancel button is shown using `[self.searchBar showsCancelButton:YES animated:YES]`. The keyboard is dismissed using `[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder]`.

Comment: For a robust answer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968595/how-to-enable-cancel-button-with-uisearchbar/47617904#47617904

Answer (score 20):

Call to `[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder]` will make the cancel button disabled. Hence, you should always update cancel button to enable after calling it.

**Objective-C**

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)[searchBar valueForKey:@"cancelButton"];
[cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
if let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    cancelButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

In my experience, `view.endEditing(true)` is the problem. Because it's also called `.resignFirstResponder` if there's a UITextField inside the view, which is contained in UISearchBar.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting

Comment: Put this in searchBarTextDidEndEditing and wrap it in DispatchQueue.main.async

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me to handle any dismissal such as `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`, `view.endEditing(false)`, interactive swipe to dismiss, presenting a view controller, etc.

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        //cancel button becomes disabled when search bar isn't first responder, force it back enabled
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
                cancelButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Making sure to set `searchBar.delegate = self`.

Comment: I can confirm this solution for iOS 17.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 4.0

```
if let cancelButton : UIButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton{
    cancelButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: As of iOS 13, this use of private API is caught and leads to a crash, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @JanNash thanks for noticing the bug. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the runtime API to access the cancel button.

```
UIButton *btnCancel = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"];
[btnCancel setEnabled:YES];
```

As far as your question is concerned, there is no way you can enable the cancel button when the keyboard is dismissed, like there is no callback as such.

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 7 all the subview of UISearchBar are one level deeper. This should work:

```
for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
           [(UIButton *)view setEnabled:YES];
        }
}
```

Still hacky and can easily break in the next iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self enableCancelButton];
}

- (void)enableCancelButton {
    for (UIView *view in _seachBar.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [(UIButton *)view setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

***BUT*** this is a pretty hackish method and I'm fairly certain it's generally frowned upon by Apple and could potentially lead to the app being rejected. As far as I know, there doesn't seem to be any other way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution that is working for me.

`func enableButtons(_ view:UIView) {
        for subView in view.subviews {
            enableButtons(subView)
        }
        if let buttonView = view as? UIButton {
            buttonView.isEnabled = true
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution, works perfect for me

```
extension UISearchBar {

    func enableCancelButton(in view: UIView) {

        view.subviews.forEach {
            enableCancelButton(in: $0)
        }

        if let cancelButton = view as? UIButton {
            cancelButton.isEnabled = true
            cancelButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.enableCancelButton(in: searchBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? References, context etc

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below searchBarShouldEndEditing delegate method in your code. Hope it will helpful.

```
(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    [[searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"] setEnabled:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: For me, the cancelButton is still enabled at that point, so it doesn't help enabling it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
(searchBar.value(forKey: "_cancelButton") as? UIButton)?.isEnabled = true
```