# iPhone SDK: Not able to access TextField From SearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

I have created one custom Searchbar with Cancle button. I want to **Enable** **cancel** **button** Everytime.but it enable only after i start editing search bar.
I wrote following Code.

```
#pragma mark - Search Bar Methods

-(void)addSearchBar{

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

  for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [self.searchBar subviews]) {    
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {    
      @try {
        // set style of keyboard
        [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

        // always force return key to be enabled
        [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
      }
      @catch (NSException * e) {        
        // ignore exception
      }
    }
  }



}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [btnSearch setEnabled:TRUE];

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

But i am not able to get textField from its subviews.
Please Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968595/how-to-enable-cancel-button-with-uisearchbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code for getting textfield from searchbar

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
        for (UIView *searchView in subView.subviews){
            if ([searchView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                {

                [(UITextField *)searchView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
                [(UITextField *)searchView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
                break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect!!. Works, Thanks.