# ios 13 - Custom SearchBar with UISearchBar _searchField not working

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, xcode11, ios13

Before Xcode-11-Beta (ios13) below code for custom searchbar value for key to get textField working fine. Now getting below crash log.

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Access to UISearchBar's _searchField ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug'

```
- (UITextField *)textField
{
 return [self valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Never use `valueForKey:` to dig into the private subview structure of standard components. It was never valid and it always ends up breaking after a while. Work with the provide public API to do what you need.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for valuable feedback. But for customize UISearchBar already did it. So, now what's solutions.

Comment: How i am understanding we don't have no one solution?

Comment: @PratikSodha - check this [UISearchBarSearchField BackgroundView color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127704/uisearchbarsearchfield-backgroundview-color)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The SDK now provides [`UISearchBar.searchTextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/3175433-searchtextfield) so you can simply replace your private API implementation with the public API.

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: but now the code doesn't compile on the previous xcode... any suggestions?

Comment: And if you need to support iOS 12 and below but you're compiling with Xcode 11?

Comment: Wrap it in `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {}` if you need to support earlier iOS versions. You won’t be able to use an older version of Xcode when building for iOS 13.

Comment: @JordanH you answer is ok , but i need to support xCode10 also anyone can help me

Answer (score 24):

If we want to support iOS 12 and earlier also while compiling with Xcode 11, then we can make an extension of `UISearchBar` where we can grab the textfield

```
extension UISearchBar {

    var textField : UITextField? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return self.searchTextField
        } else { // Fallback on earlier versions
            for subview in subviews.first?.subviews ?? [] {
                if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
                    return textField
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

USAGE

```
searchBar.textField?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
```

Here we can access all textField's properties and modify as per our needs in `UISearchBar`

There is a change in the view hierarchy.
So by printing `self.subviews[0]).subviews` where `self` in `UISearchBar`

For **iOS 12** and earlier

[image]

For **iOS 13+**

[image]

Along with `UISearchBarBackground`, now we have `UISearchBarSearchContainerView` and `UISearchBarScopeContainerView` whereas `UISearchBarTextField` is missing which is replaced by an extension provided by Apple in `UISearchTextField` class

```
extension UISearchBar {

    
    open var searchTextField: UISearchTextField { get }
}
```

So we can directly access `searchBar.searchTextField` in iOS 13 and above devices whereas it will lead to a crash if we try to access this property in iOS 12 and below OS devices.

The crash will be like this:

> [UISearchBar searchTextField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

[image]

Here is the Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/3175433-searchtextfield) for this

Comment: Why does Xcode compiler not throw a warning when the iOS deployment target is set to < 13.0? Doesn't that happen usually when using an API that is not available on the deployment target version? And isn't that an essential job of a pre-compiler? 

Comment: Yes, and UISearchTextField IS marked in (e.g. typing "UISearchTextField * textfield" does give me a warning), but unfortunately, the property "searchBar.searchTextField" isn't marked as iOS13 only in the SDK.

Comment: Crash on iOS 12 when I call becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: Last time I checked (on Xcode 11.6) this property finally flagged as iOS 13+. It was about time...

Answer (score 22):

I had the same crash, with IOS 13 you don't need anymore the .value(forKey:)

Here is the line that caused the crash:

```
if let searchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField {
```

And this was the fix:

```
let searchField = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
```

Comment: How did you find the line that caused the crash?

Comment: It worked but my question is earlier value for key method used to work normally, now on xcode 11.2.1 what it causing it to crash?

Comment: This helped me after days of nightmares

Answer (score 9):

Do this:

```
 var searchTextField: UITextField?
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchTextField = searchBar.searchTextField
    } else {
        if let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            searchTextField = searchField
        }
    }
```

This will give you search bar's text field appropriately based on version check.

Answer (score 7):

It still works for me with key "searchField" without underscore. Swift 5

```
guard let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField else { return }
```

Comment: You have to do it this way if you are still using Xcode 10 since there is no "searchTextField" of SDK 10 UISearchBar. But when running under iOS 13 if will work. `        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        } else {
            return value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField
`

Comment: is it a private API? will Apple reject the app to app store?

Answer (score 4):

If u want check iOS Version!

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
 } else {
    searchBar.textField.clearButtonMode = .never
 }
```

Dont Forget the extension:

```
extension UISearchBar {

 var textField : UITextField{
    return self.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
 }
}
```

Comment: Day saving answer!
Hint: For me, it just worked without the underscore (`self.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField`)

Answer (score 3):

Removed the "_" Underscore (while trying to access property) everywhere and it worked for all iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UISearchBar {

    var textField : UITextField? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return self.searchTextField
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make check like this for iOS 11 and the earlier versions:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *){
            self.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by Name"
            self.searchBar.setSerchFont(textFont: UIFont(name:AppFontLato.Regular, size:14.0 * DeviceInfo.aspectRatio()))
            self.searchBar.setSerchTextcolor(color: Colors.black51)
        }
        else{
            if let searchTextField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField, let clearButton = searchTextField.value(forKey: "_clearButton") as? UIButton {
                searchTextField.placeholder = "Search by Name"
                searchTextField.font = UIFont(name:AppFontLato.Regular, size:14.0 * DeviceInfo.aspectRatio())
                searchTextField.textColor = Colors.black51
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting crash on cancel button value forkey. Is it possible to customize cancel button in iOS 13.[image]

Comment: How are you accessing the cancel button?

Comment: let cancelButton =  searchBar.value(forKey: "_cancelButton")as? UIButton @mohsin

Comment: Fixed the issue by removing the underscore before the key.  
```Swift

let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton")as? UIButton

```

Comment: Yes, remove "_" from wherever you are trying to access. It will work for almost all versions

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this answer, working fine in iOS 13:-**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60503506/9863222

Answer (score 0):

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        self.searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        if let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            searchField.clearButtonMode = .never
        }
    }
```