# UISearchBarSearchField BackgroundView color

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

[image]I am trying to change the background color of the search bar text field and i have searched and tried lots of solutions but those are not working.

So, please anyone can tell me the exact solution for that. How can we change the background color of the search bar text field?

```
/// used to prepare searchController inside navigation.
private func prepareNavigationSearchControllerSetup() {
    self.title = AppConstant.kContacts
    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search.searchBar.cornerRadius = 10.0
    search.searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor = .red
    search.searchBar.textField?.tintColor = .yellow
    self.navigationItem.searchController = search
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

extension UISearchBar {

    var textField: UITextField? {
        let subViews = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        return (subViews.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot more search I found the correct answer that is working for me.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let textfield = search.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue

            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
            }
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).backgroundColor = .yellow
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).tintColor = .blue
```

**Output**

[image]

> Edit : Full Code

```
    var searchController = UISearchController()
    let resultsTableController = Storyboard.Home.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GlobalTableVC") as! GlobalTableVC
    resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self
    resultsTableController.tableView.dataSource = self

    resultsTableController.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchCell")

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "EB033B")

    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).backgroundColor = .yellow
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).tintColor = .blue


    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: can you please tell me where should I put the above code?

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh In `prepareNavigationSearchControllerSetup`. I think your `search.searchBar.textField?.tintColor` & `search.searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor`  is not working so you can replace lines here

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh Check full code. There is button in navbar, on btnaction I have called this code. Your requirement might vary and you need to code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 13:

```swift
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .red
            searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = .yellow
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 17, the only thing that worked for me was [SuperDuperTango](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204250/superdupertango)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751292/cannot-change-search-bar-background-color?rq=3) and I did the following to remove that overlay.

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
```

and then re-apply a corner radius

```
searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe in the future someone still needs it, I tried this code and it works!

```
if let searchTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
    searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // Change this to the desired color
}
```