# SearchController in iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, ios13

I am adding searchController in navigationItem on action. In iOS12, it shows properly but in iOS 13 it is not showing. On debugging view hierarchy, it is showing that searchbar is been added but its height has been set to zero. Cant trace the proper solution.

**Code :**

```
func setupSearchController() {

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as UISearchBarDelegate
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true 

    if let textfield = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

        textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue

        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        self.tblView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

**In Debug Navigator,**

[image]

**In Size Inspector,**

[image]

Comment: What if you remove all that hacky code where you mess with the search field`s text field?

Comment: @matt It is still the same as above

Comment: see this for help : [UISearchBarSearchField BackgroundView color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127704/uisearchbarsearchfield-backgroundview-color)

Comment: Its answer has the same code which I have written here, but it still didn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting frame for search bar

```
searchController. searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

[image]

Perhaps your navigation bar is collapsed? If your navigation item's `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` property is `true`, the navigation bar can collapse to conceal the search bar.

Comment: It is working fine, but now my tableview is under it, as it is unable to update its frame, also when we click on searchbar, it is calling didselect of tableview as it is under its frame. So searchController when added is not becoming active